# Check usable components for model

Tags: python, django

**models.py:**

```
class CarType(models.Model):
    engine = models.CharField()
    transmission = models.CharField()


class Car(models.Model):
    car_type = models.ForeignKey(CarType,)
    color ...

class Details(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, blank=True, null=True, related_name='details')
    engine = models.CharField()
    transmission = models.CharField()
```

For example, we have BMW car. This type of car need to install only engine class A+.

Then, when we add a new details to our car (we can add new car with details too), we need to check - is a detail, that we want to install, is the same, that this car type support.

So, we need always and everywhere check, what details we add of which car type, what car we create with what details.

If we add engine class B to our BMW (needs engine class A+), raise some exception.

The save method in Car class not enough, because we can add new detail to car  through Detail class.

How would you solved this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: can you be more clear ? I really do not understand your question...

Comment: @Charlesthk what the method and where (I think in Car class) need to create with described logic in my first message. Or we need to use middleware?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom validator.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_a(instance):
    if instance.engine != 'A+':
        raise ValidationError('Instance requires A+ class engine')
```

Then in models.py

```
...
class Car(models.Model):
    ...
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, 
                            blank=True,
                            null=True
                            related_name='details',
                            validators=[validate_a])
```

Comment: And how we get 'A+'? We need to compare Details engine and car type engine.

Comment: You can just put the validator in Details, go instance.car_type.engine. This is super simple

Comment: Do you have a mistake? class Detail in your code, right?